# ServiceStack set Response DTO when ending the response in Request Filter

Tags: c#, servicestack

I use ServiceStack to create an API. I want to perform authentication in a Request Filter. I have created a class that inherits RequestFilterAttribute and overrides method

```
void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
```

In the override when the authentication fails, I want to prevent the request to continue with the service method and I want to return a specific message. For ending the request I can use one of these methods:

```
res.Close();
res.End();
res.EndHttpHandlerRequest();
res.EndRequest();
res.EndRequestWithNoContent();
```

They prevent the execution of the method in the service. When ending the response I want to have a specific DTO with a message. So before ending the response, I assign a DTO object to the property

```
res.Dto = myResponseDto;
```

However, the result from the API call is without any data. Can anybody help with preventing in the filter a request to reach the ServiceStack service implementation, but returning the desired DTO response object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With filters you have to handle the raw response. So if you want to end the response in the filter and return a DTO response, you will need to `Write` the DTO object to the response before calling the `EndRequest` method.

*If you are sending an `Unauthorized` error then setting the status code to `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` (401) is usually all that is needed by a client to recognise their request failed.*

```cs
public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
{
    // Perform you filter actions

    if(authorised)
        return;

    // Not authorised, return some object

    var responseDto = new {
        SomeValue = "You are not authorised to do that."
    };

    // Set the status code
    res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

    // You may need to handle other return types based on `req.AcceptTypes`
    // This example assumes JSON response.

    // Set the content type
    res.ContentType = "application/json";

    // Write the object
    res.Write(responseDto.toJson());

    // End the request
    req.EndRequest();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! This solves my problem, though I thought there is a way to do this automatically, as most of the stuff in ServiceStack. In that way I should take care for the different response content types which my API supports. However, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following instructions, where `res.Dto` can be changed to whatever you feel like:

```
res.ContentType = req.ResponseContentType;
res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
res.Dto = DtoUtils.CreateResponseDto(requestDto, new ResponseStatus("401", "Unauthorized"));
res.EndRequest();
```

If you do not require to embed data in the response, you can simply use `throw new AuthenticationException("Error reason");` in your filter.

Comment: I have tried it, but it does not work. I'm getting Content-Length: 0 and no response